# Can you paint a tile on sprite overlap? Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi all I'm trying to make a game where I can drive around and as I pass over certain tiles in my tile-map they change colour, dead simple problem in my head. However not sure how to change the painted tile on overlap, my thinking was I could use sprite collision detection but when I put my sprites on the same z-axis height they overlay and are no longer visible. Is there something I have missed or a more efficient way of going about this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.